# table sorter not working on content reloaded with ajax

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a very weird problem.
On my site I have two very similar pages.
They have a tab menu which reloads a div using ajax.

On this page

http://football-tennis-stats.com/index.php/stats/display_fotbal/

table sorting works even after changing the country tab.

On this one ,it doesn't.

http://football-tennis-stats.com/index.php/stats/injury_list

I think the code is identical for both pages.

On the working page I have

/get table results....

```
$this->load->view('stats/football_tables',$data);

$this->load->view('stats/ajax_table_sorter.html');
```

On the page which doesn't work I have

```
$this->load->view('stats/injuries',$data);
$this->load->view('stats/ajax_table_sorter.html');
```

ajax_table_sorter is just a simple view (I use Code Igniter)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function ()
{

$('table').tablesorter();
```

});

As far as I read you have to reload the call the table sorter plugin again,which as you can see,I do.
Any help is much apreciated.

Comment: I noticed that when loading the injury_list page (the one that doesn't work ) I get this error in the firebug console,h[list[i][0]] is undefined ,but it still works the first time I load the page.It stops working after I click on a tab(reload with AJAX)

Answer (score 0):

You have this code embedded in your http://football-tennis-stats.com/js/table_sorter.js file, and it throws an error when it tries to sort the second table (contry, injury count) on http://football-tennis-stats.com/index.php/stats/injury_list because the are only two columns:

```
$("table").tablesorter({ 
    // sort on the first column and third column, order asc 
    sortList: [[0,0],[2,0]] 
});
```

You are trying to force a sort on the first and third columns, so an error is thrown.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/styson/QvGgD/1/) using your tablesorter code and similar tables.